# How do i split multiple numbers from a list with only one value

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to split my code below seperately so that i can extract the number value but im unsure as to how i can do so

```
Output = subprocess.check_output('grep "ip_forward" sysctl.conf; exit 0', shell=True)
output = "".join(re.split("[A-Z,a-z, =, #, _, .]",Output))
```

the output that i get from the subprocess is

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

the output that i get from the variable output is

```
41
```

Comment: What output do you expect to achieve?

Comment: i just need the value 1 (after the '=' sign)

Comment: Do you need to use regex? Can you not just `Output.split('-')[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```py
string = "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1"
print (string.split("=",1)[1])
```

**Output**

```
"1"
```

*Note this is of type string not type int*

Split takes the word (or character) to split on and optionally a limit to the number of splits.

This example splits on "=".

You can read more on splits [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)